# Nativescript video on canvas doesn't work

Tags: canvas, video, webview, nativescript

I have to develop an android application in Nativescript. In which I have to provide video files play on canvas.
The app contain WebView component which loads html file, where includes fabric.js plugin for canvas implementation. Inline video autoplays on webview loaded. Here is shorten version of code, which properly works on web pages, but not in WebView component.

**html**

```
<video id="video-bg" src="bg.mp4" muted loop playsinline autoplay></video>    
<div id="canvas-container">
    <div id="canvas-touch-prevent"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var videoBg = document.getElementById("video-bg");
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var cW = canvas.getWidth();
var cH = canvas.getHeight();
videoBg.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    var video = new fabric.Image(videoBg, {
        name: 'video',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        selectable: false,
        cursor: 'none',
        objectCaching: false,
    });
    video.scaleToHeight(cH);
    video.scaleToWidth(cW);
    canvas.add(video);
}
```

Can anyone please help with video on canvas in Nativescript WebView ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review [ask], and update with more details on what "it doesn't work" means.  What errors are you seeing, what output are you seeing, etc.?

Comment: Is it iOS or Android?